# How to kill wine processes when they crash or are going to crash?

Tags: wine

Sometimes it happens that a Wine application crashes (slowing down the system and making it almost unusable).
In most cases I'm able to kill the program with `xkill`, but sometime I've to restart as Ubuntu seems not to respond very well (the only thing that works is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, the launcher; `xkill` doesn't).
I've tried to use `wineboot -r` or `-f` but they don't seem to work very well..
If something is unclear, let me know I'll try to explain better :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
killall nameofexefile.exe
```

just like linux processes

Comment: is this just for wine or for all running process in linux?

Comment: this will kill any process, windows via wine, or linux

Comment: So wineserver -k will kill all wine processes... it's what I meant...
I don't use killall <file>.exe as often I don't know the exact name of the file (and when the system goes crazy I won't know in any case)

Comment: ahhh right then in that case wineserver -k will probably do the job. Just be careful you don't have any other wine processes open, that includes programs in PlayOnLinux and Crossover too.

Answer (score 42):

You can safely kill wine sessions either via ALT+F2 or via a terminal by typing

```
wineserver -k
```

If it is really doesnt want to shutdown then you can force it via

```
wineserver -k9
```

Comment: I still see `winedevice.exe` running after I execute these commands.

Answer (score 9):

Well, as a wine programmer, I often will munge up the whole damn thing, so I use my super special killwine script. This is a hard death (`wineserver -k` is the nice way to do it and always preferred).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

wine_cellar="${HOME}/.local/share/wine"

if (($#)); then
    if [[ -e "${wine_cellar}/$1" ]]; then
        WINEPREFIX="${wine_cellar}/$1"
        shift
    elif [[ "${1:0:1}" != "-" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: Didn't understand argument '$1'?" >&2;
        exit 1
    fi
fi

if ((${#WINEPREFIX})); then
    pids=$(
        grep -l "WINEPREFIX=${WINEPREFIX}$" $(
            ls -l /proc/*/exe 2>/dev/null |
            grep -E 'wine(64)?-preloader|wineserver' |
            perl -pe 's;^.*/proc/(\d+)/exe.*$;/proc/$1/environ;g;'
        ) 2> /dev/null |
        perl -pe 's;^/proc/(\d+)/environ.*$;$1;g;'
    )
else
    pids=$(
        ls -l /proc/*/exe 2>/dev/null |
        grep -E 'wine(64)?-preloader|wineserver' |
        perl -pe 's;^.*/proc/(\d+)/exe.*$;$1;g;'
    )
fi

if ((${#pids})); then
    set -x
    kill $* $pids
fi
```

This assumes that you're wine prefixes are under `~/.local/share/wine`. Usage examples are:

```bsh
killwine                       # Just kill all instances of wine
killwine -9                    # Hard kill them all
killwine lotro                 # Only kill wine under ${HOME}/.local/share/wine/lotro
killwine -INT lotro            # Same as above, but use SIGINT
WINEPREFIX=/tmp/crap killwine  # Kill only the instance under /tmp/crap
sudo reboot                    # Pretend you're running windows.
```

I don't know, but I don't think you'll often end up with various processes hung in memory (what this script takes care of) on a normal or even normal+staging release, but I do quite a lot because of hacking the server and ntdll.

EDIT: This script will only work on a Linux-based OS and assumes that the proc file system is mounted on /proc, etc.

Comment: Works like a charm, while wineserver -k or -k9 didn't succeed.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I seem to have lost my copy of this script and now I have it again! I should mention that this will only work on a Linux-based OS, as it digs through /proc.

Answer (score 4):

My version:

```
ls -l /proc/*/exe 2>/dev/null | grep -E 'wine(64)?-preloader|wineserver' | perl -pe 's;^.*/proc/(\d+)/exe.*$;$1;g;' | xargs -n 1 kill
```

It kills all wine processes. Thanks to this post https://askubuntu.com/a/732320/605355

Comment: lol, that's a snippet from my script! :)  They just changed it to pipe to xargs instead of a bash sub-shell -- that's good because it will also work with /bin/sh.  I've still had some processes not die though, when they hang prior to finishing the process init stuff in ntdll.  Maybe I should try to submit my script, or some incarnation of it to mainline.  EDIT: Oh, I see, that's your modified version :)

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to have the same problem.
This command in terminal helped me. Press Ctrl + Alt + t and then write the following:
`ps -x | grep "Your program name" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`

Your program name should be written **without quotes**,
It helped me solving oblivion.exe:
`ps -x | grep Oblivion | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill`