# winebrowser starts if i clicking at links in element client

Tags: kubuntu, wine, winetricks

i use [Element is a messenger desktop client](https://element.io/get-started)

since weeks i have problem when i click on a hyperlink.

### Example:

some send me this message:

> hi https://duckduckgo.com is great

if i click to

> https://duckduckgo.com
> winebrowser is opend into the task menu.
> it never stopps.
> over time I have a large number of such windows in the task menu.

what could i do? i don't want use winebrowser if i use [element-desktop client](https://element.io/get-started). it has normaly nothing to do with wine.

i tried the two tips here [How to kill wine processes when they crash or are going to crash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52341/how-to-kill-wine-processes-when-they-crash-or-are-going-to-crash) are not effective

they has no effect.

#### System

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

$ whereis wine
wine: /usr/bin/wine /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine /usr/lib/wine /usr/share/wine /usr/share/man/man1/wine.1.gz

$ whereis winetricks
winetricks: /usr/bin/winetricks /usr/share/man/man1/winetricks.1.gz

$ whereis element-desktop
element-desktop: /usr/bin/element-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

this change solved this problem for me. I can't explain it exactly. trail and Error. Intuition. Maybe someone else can explain this well.

changed **Default Applications > in application based on the contents of the URL**:

[image: Default Applications > in application based on the contents of the URL]

to **Default Applications > always Firefox**:

[image: Default Applications > always Firefox]