# How to kill all Wine process exiting an script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, wine, games

I'm ussing some simple bash scripts to launch many "old" directx games using Wine,  (launch from EmulationStation):

#!/bin/bash

cd "path/of/th/game"

wine executable.exe

My problem is that since I updated to wine 7.x versions from wine 6.x, after exits a game some process must be open, and do not able to me to suthdown the computer (sometimes cannot exit the game with ESC or ATL+F4).

So, what I could add to my bash script launcher to kill all wine process on exit (after pressing ALT + F4)?

Many thanks in advice.

Comment: should be adding a ```kill``` command of what processes that you are running and want to stop. more info here : [Kill Command Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kill-command-in-linux-with-examples/)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/928094/15811 does not answer your question?